# How to read a text file in reverse using python 2.2

Tags: python

Is there a way to read a text file in reverse for Python 2.2?
Thanks for the help =)

Comment: Please show us [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: As a note, none of the answers in the duplicate question answer this one since they all use features > 2.2. Apart from maybe the very low level answers, which are complete overkill.

Answer (score 0):

try the following.

```
# method not using the `reverse` function
def read_file_reversed(filename):
    return open(filename, 'r').readlines()[::-1]
```

It reverses the list using slicing.
Be mindful that these will load the entire file into memory.

Comment: I believe you mean `reversed`, which was released in 2.4.  Also, files have a `readlines` method which returns a list, so there is no need for the list comprehension.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I meant `list.reverse()` but misread it in the docs. Where would I find when that was introduced? I usually use list comprehension to allow for extra processing as the list is being constructed, but you're correct its not needed here.

Comment: @Serdalis: just search for reversed in the latest python doc. http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed says new in 2.4

Comment: @Anthon heh I feel stupid for missing that, thanks. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Serdalis: older docs are still available, just not made with sphinx. http://docs.python.org/release/2.2/

Comment: Does the filename only put the name of the file with the extension or the whole file directory. I am very noob in python. Started a few weeks ago.

Comment: @SalihinAlim filename does include the directory :)